p4v Get Latest Revision File is worked but directory doesn't work
I am working on writing code using the Perforce API to "Get Latest Revision" of a folder inside a specified Depot Path when an application is executed.
The issue I am encountering is that when I set the Depot Path as a file location, the "Get Latest Revision" works correctly, but when I set it as a folder location, the files within the folder do not "Get Latest Revision."
Below is the code I am using.
I would appreciate your help.
private static void GetLatestRevision()
{
    string serverUri = Dict_Config["ServerURI"];
    Server server = new Server(new ServerAddress(serverUri));

    Repository rep = new Repository(server);

    try
    {
        Connection con = rep.Connection;
        con.Connect(null); 


        con.UserName = Dict_Config["P4VUserName"];
        con.Connect(new Options() { { "Password", Dict_Config["P4VUserPassword"] } });

        if (con == null)
        {
            return;
        }


        string clientName = Dict_Config["P4VClientName"];

        Client client = rep.GetClient(clientName);

        if (client == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        con.Client = client;

        if (con.Client == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string depotPath = //depot/main/MyFolder/... **← Not Worked**
        string depotPath = //depot/main/MyFolder/...#head **← Not Worked**
        string depotPath = //depot/main/MyFolder/MyFile.json **← This is worked!**


        PathSpec targetPath = new DepotPath(depotPath);
        Options syncOptions = new Options(SyncFilesCmdFlags.Force, 0);
        FileSpec syncFile = new FileSpec(new DepotPath(depotPath), null);
        
        con.Client.SyncFiles(syncOptions, new FileSpec[] { syncFile });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (rep.Connection != null)
            rep.Connection.Disconnect();

        Environment.Exit(0);    
    }
}


Check the error message that comes back from the server and make sure the file path ends in ... (three dots, not a Unicode ellipsis or anything like that).

@Samwise thank you for advice. I used three dots end of path string. I'll try to check server error

I found reason. As you command, text type 'utf-8' was problem. thank you for answer :)!
